# Mapping a default key binding in vim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I want to remap `Ctrl-]` which is used for jumping to the tags to another key binding.

These mappings work:

```
:map <F2> <C-]>
:map <A-1> <C-]>
```

But this mapping doesn't work:

```
:map <C-1> <C-]>
```

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: What does Vim show when you type `<C-v><C-1>`? I think it must be possible to map this in Gvim, but I do not think that you will be able to map this in Vim.

Comment: And, it is good to use `*noremap` instead of `*map` unless you know that you definitely need to use `*map`. It can save your time because you may run into the situation when your mapping does not work as expected because some characters are remapped somewhere else.

Comment: Failed to map `<C-1>` in gvim-7.2.303, typing `<C-1>` just produces `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is not a valid ASCII character. From [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

(search for "^^" or "^@" to see the table )

you will see that there are several keybindings such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

so you are not actually calling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> but their ASCII equivalents.

VIM is designed to be lightweight and fairly platform independent. so if it isn't in the list of ASCII characters you cannot make a binding to it.

Comment: I tried <C-,> and other symbols as well. I cannot map them neither.

Answer (score 0):

It might be getting trapped/filtered by your OS.  If you check the mappings, is it listed?

Comment: Yes I can see it in the mappings list.